# Running API Level 24+ on VS Emulator for Android (Hyper-V)

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-emulator

I have been using the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) to test my Xamarin apps and I am very impressed with the performance of Hyper-V over HAXM. However I can't seem to find any options for emulating anything past 6.0 API Level 23:

[image]

Is there any way to download additional system images for API levels greater than 23?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82871/how-to-add-new-api-levels-to-visual-studio-emulator-for-android) and [corroborated here](https://blog.rthand.com/post/2017/05/02/good-bye-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-and-hello-problems.aspx), there will be no support for levels above 23 and they recommend that use the improved emulator that comes with the Android SDK. Here's the quote:

> From Microsoft:
>
> Hello,
>
> This is an automated message. Unfortunately, we have no plans to
>   publish Android images past 4.4. We recommend that you try Google or
>   GenyMotion’s emulator for future images of the Android operating
>   system.
>
> When we first released the Visual Studio Android emulator, the Google
>   emulator was slow, out-of-date, and a significant source of pain for
>   mobile developers. In addition to the great work performed by
>   GenyMotion, the Visual Studio Android Emulator proved that emulators
>   can be fast, productive tools for mobile development.
>
> Since then, Google has responded to developer feedback by increasing
>   their investment in their tools. The next generation Google Android
>   Emulator has closed the feature gap that previously differentiated
>   Visual Studio’s emulator. Google’s emulator has become much faster and
>   more feature rich.
>
> We also know that, for mobile developers, authenticity is key. We
>   believe that Google, as the platform owner, is best positioned to
>   provide ongoing support for new versions of the platform in a way that
>   accurately and authentically reflects the real-world behavior on
>   devices.
>
> For developers like you who’ve come to love and depend on the VS
>   Android Emulator, thank you! We will continue to support in-market
>   platform images according to Visual Studio’s generous support policy.
>   However, Microsoft will no longer produce new Android images for the
>   VS Android Emulator. We consider this a successful project that has
>   come to a natural conclusion.
>
> Happy coding!

Comment: You might think the VS emulator is completely abandoned but in the 2nd link Miguel mentions they are working on a solution. On Twitter Nov. 8, 2017 the Visual Studio account was asked if newer images would be made available. They replied _"There's no info yet...stay tuned"_ [link](https://twitter.com/VisualStudio/status/928265854264987648)

Comment: The visual studio emulator gave me more headaches than the google one!

Comment: The google emulator gave me more headaches than the visual studio one!

Comment: So there is really no way at all to develop Android apps on a machine where I **need** Hyper-V to run?

Comment: Android VM acceleration works with [Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX)](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows) now.